# store values produced inside if in an array

Tags: php

I want to store in an array all the values of use_id_one that are produced inside the if statement. Any idea how to do this?

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT `user_id` FROM users WHERE (surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%') ");

while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $user_id_one = $run['user_id']; 

   $check_friend_query = mysql_query("  SELECT friends_id from friends WHERE  (user_one='$session_user_id' AND user_two ='$user_id_one') OR (user_one='$user_id_one' AND user_two='$session_user_id')   ");

    if( mysql_num_rows($check_friend_query) == 1  ){    
         echo"$user_id_one";
        //the above echo prints me all user_id_one values I want
        //how to store all these values of user_id_one in an array

    }
}
```

and how can I output them next, in order to be sure that stored correclty(for testing purpose)

Comment: Create array and fill it in with those values... I don't see a problem... $arr[] = $user_id_one will attach values to an array one by one.

Comment: any idea how to do it, because what I have tried did not work

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
echo"$user_id_one";
```

with this line

```
$array[] = $user_id_one; //this will store the $user_id_one value in the array
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following modification to the code to add the values to an array

```
$usersIdArray = array();
$index = 0;
while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $user_id_one = $run['user_id']; 

    $check_friend_query = mysql_query("  SELECT friends_id from friends WHERE  (user_one='$session_user_id' AND user_two ='$user_id_one') OR (user_one='$user_id_one' AND user_two='$session_user_id')   ");

    if( mysql_num_rows($check_friend_query) == 1  ){    
        $userIdArray[$index++] = $user_id_one;

    }
}

foreach($userIdArray as $userId) {
    echo $userId;
}
```

Comment: I believe a better syntax would be `$userIdArray[] = $user_id_one;`, since it reduces the overhead of one additional variable while achieving identical effect.